# Can a part of a soundwave also sounds a bit higher?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

A soundwave has a certain wavelength. If you hear a half wavelength it is enough to hear this sound. But if you only receive a part of that half soundwave that wave sounds a bit weaker but is it possible that it also sounds a bit higher because the partwave has become more of less shorter?

Comment: Where did you hear that half a wavelength is enough for a frequency determination? Are you referring to the sampling theorem? That's not what the sampling theorem means.

Comment: A half wavelength has already a high peak  and a vale so the total difference in air pressure is there

Comment: It depends on how much we know about the shape of the wave. If we know that the wave is sinusoidal, then we can reconstruct its frequency, amplitude and phase from three samples that are no more than half a period (or wavelength) apart, i.e. it could also be a tiny fraction of half a period. This follows from there being three independent parameters, which needs three independent equations. If we don't know that the wave is sinusoidal, then we need more samples and we also have to be careful with whether the function is even or odd.

Comment: lets assume that it is sinusoidal, than you can reconstruct the sound but the question is whether the a fraction of a wave can sounds higher?

Comment: See http://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/28163/whats-the-shortest-sound-perceptible-to-the-human-ear

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question completely... :-) Yes, shorter impulses will sound "higher", up to a point. In the limit all half-wave pulses shorter than approx. $10-20\mu s$ will probably sound the same. At that point the low end of their spectrum (up to 20kHz) doesn't change much anymore.

Answer (score 2):

The shorter a sample of a frequency you hear, the less distinct a frequency you associate with it and the more it sounds just like a "click".  (This happens with much longer sound samples than half wavelengths in practice)  Two good ways of thinking about why this happens come to to mind.  One is using a model of how the ears processes sound, and the other is using Fourier transforms.

A very simplified (but good enough for us here) model of the human ear would look like a microscopic xylophone, with hairs of different resonant frequencies up to ~20kHz, each connected to a nerve which detects the vibration of that hair.  So if the ear is subject to a long sample of a sinusoidal sound, there are one or two hairs that resonate very strongly and dominate the nerve signals, so we hear a clear pitch.  And if the ear is subject to a short pressure anomaly (like a single half wavelength sample) than all of the hairs with periods longer than the duration  of the anomaly will be excited to a similar extent, and all those with shorter periods will be much less excited.  So you hear a click or thud with no distinct pitch, and the "crispness" of the sound determined by how short and sharp edged the anomaly was.

If you would like a more precisely defined method of decomposing sound samples into characteristic frequencies, I suggest you try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_analysis. There are many interesting results to be found by decomposing truncated samples.  The results will not be exactly the same as with the ear model I used above, but I think you'll find that they will be qualitatively similar in the case of a half wavelength sample.

I also suggest you check out this previous question to see discussion of what very brief click-like samples sound like and how audible they are in practice: https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/28163/whats-the-shortest-sound-perceptible-to-the-human-ear